# Good rejoinder to "agree to disagree"

Tags: antonyms

Sometimes people say "Let's just agree to disagree" as a kind of rhetorical weapon to prematurely shut down discussion that is just getting started. Is there a good reposte, or antonym expression, other than, "FU"?

What is the witty way to **NOT** "agree to disagree"?

Note this is not the same as this thread:
[Alternative to "We'll just have to agree to disagree"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160556/alternative-to-well-just-have-to-agree-to-disagree)

It's pretty much an antonym question :)

Comment: No, let's not...

Comment: What @Clare said.  or with a bit of humor, “unfortunately this needs to be a fight to the death.”

Comment: WHile it's not the same question, there are many ideas in comments to the original question and the answer the user accepted that are relevant, so it's worth checking out for people who want to answer.

Comment: "I challenge you to a duel!"

Comment: The question is too broad. And primarily opinion-based. Not to mention that a riposte to such a statement is generally misguided. The point of the statement is to request that both parties *stop* with the rejoinders. If you need to keep riposting then you haven't gotten the message, methinks. It is difficult to productively argue with someone who does not want to argue with you. Or are you perhaps just looking for the last word? (You can tell that I do *not* think of such a statement as a "*rhetorical weapon*". I don't see it being used that way.)

Comment: “No, let’s disagree to disagree.”

Comment: I don't think it's opinion based. I think it calls for imagination and a sense of repartee.

Comment: And a sense of ***humor***.

Comment: Yes can it be done with panache and charm,to keep things going, rather than rage quitting the conversation? Also, my question is also whether there is a *standard* response (an antonym), perhaps an English convention of which I am unaware. For all I know there is a standard reply in the underground thesaurus...Saying a response is 'misguided' assumes the original use is not premature. E.g., "The number 2 is even". "I think it is odd". "Umm actually no." "Well let's agree to disagree."  In this context a friendly rejoinder would be called for, no?

Comment: @Drew what I'm saying is maybe we should just agree to disagree. Don't downvote me brah

Comment: I disagree with that.

Comment: After the other person says, "We'll have to agree to disagree," now you get to have the last word in the debate, but you have to make it pithy.  You can refer the person to the authoritative source that backs up your position (a source you have explained in a less succinct way earlier in the discussion).  For example, "Check the manual.  I think you'll find it does allow for such-and-so."  I'm sorry it's not witty, I'm not very witty.

Comment: @neuronet There is no standard response. How could there be?? The standard response was: Let's agree to disagree. After that, All Bets are Off. :)

Comment: Closing this was bleh, but the fact that it was closed suggests that the right answer was apparently, "There is no standard response in English." That is the contingent state of English right now. ..Until I come up with the perfect riposte!

Answer (score 1):

1) If you say so, and the devil take the hindmost. :)

2) Not on your life, bro [sis, man, mate, you old curmudgeon]

3) Not a chance, [see above]

4) If you don't mind, I'll pass on that.

5) If I'm not mistaken, compromise is out of the question.

6) You must be taking the piss, right?

7) FAT CHANCE :)

8) Well, I wouldn't want to be betting the family silver on this.

[sigh] can't think of any more of 'em.

Comment: Thanks for taking up trying to answer, in the spirit of the question. None are perfect, but number 1 is good.